# Sticky sidebar visibility at page refresh

Tags: jquery, wordpress, sidebar, sticky, page-refresh

i use twentyfifteen WP theme's sticky sidebar script for my twentyeleven-child theme. Everything works well, even the sidebar remains at its last position at page refresh (as i wished). The only small problem is that when the visitor refreshes the page, the sidebar does not appear, visitor must start to scroll to see the sidebar in its place.

I use Jquery v. 1.11.3

The script :

```
( function( $ ) {
    var $body, $window, $sidebar, adminbarOffset, top = false,
        bottom = false, windowWidth, windowHeight, lastWindowPos = 0,
        topOffset = 0, bodyHeight, sidebarHeight, resizeTimer,
        secondary, button;

        // Sidebar scrolling.
        function resize() {
            windowWidth = $window.width();

            if (1102 > windowWidth) {
                top = bottom = false;
                $sidebar.removeAttr('style');
            }
        }

        function scroll() {
            var windowPos = $window.scrollTop();

            if (1102 > windowWidth) {
                return;
            }

            sidebarHeight = $sidebar.height();
            windowHeight  = $window.height();
            bodyHeight    = $body.height();

            if (sidebarHeight + adminbarOffset > windowHeight) {
                if (windowPos > lastWindowPos) { // scroll down
                    if (top) {
                        top = false;
                        topOffset = ($sidebar.offset().top > 0) ? $sidebar.offset().top - adminbarOffset : 0;
                        $sidebar.attr('style', 'top: ' + topOffset + 'px;');
                    } else if (! bottom && windowPos + windowHeight > sidebarHeight + $sidebar.offset().top && sidebarHeight + adminbarOffset < bodyHeight) {
                        bottom = true;
                        $sidebar.attr('style', 'position: fixed; bottom: 0; margin: 0');
                        }
                } else if (windowPos < lastWindowPos) { // scroll up
                    if (bottom) {
                        bottom = false;
                        topOffset = ($sidebar.offset().top > 0) ? $sidebar.offset().top - adminbarOffset : 0;
                        $sidebar.attr('style', 'top: ' + topOffset + 'px;');
                    } else if ( ! top && windowPos + adminbarOffset < $sidebar.offset().top ) {
                        top = true;
                        $sidebar.attr('style', 'position: fixed; margin: 0');
                        }
                } else {
                    top = bottom = false;
                    topOffset = ($sidebar.offset().top > 0) ? $sidebar.offset().top - adminbarOffset : 0;
                    $sidebar.attr('style', 'top: ' + topOffset + 'px;');
                }
            } else if (! top) {
                top = true;
                $sidebar.attr('style', 'position: fixed; margin: 0');
            }

            lastWindowPos = windowPos;
        }

        function resizeAndScroll() {
            resize();
            scroll();
        }

        $(document).ready( function() {
            $body          = $(document.body);
            $window        = $(window);
            $sidebar       = $('#secondary').first();
            adminbarOffset = $body.is('.admin-bar') ? $('#wpadminbar').height() : 0;

            $window
                .on('scroll.twentyeleven', scroll)
                .on('load.twentyeleven', onResizeARIA)
                .on('resize.twentyeleven', function() {
                    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
                    resizeTimer = setTimeout(resizeAndScroll, 500);
                    onResizeARIA();
                } );
            $sidebar.on('click.twentyeleven keydown.twentyeleven', 'button', resizeAndScroll);

            *resizeAndScroll();

            for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                setTimeout(resizeAndScroll, 100 * i);
            }*
        });

} )( jQuery );
```

What to do for having the page visible at reload ? I tried to put the whole script in `$(document).load(function(){` but it did not work, probably i did not make it well or i should do something else ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the problem is that the sidebar functionality is inside the scroll() function. Export the

```
 $sidebar.attr('style'....with the fixed position and visibility visible if necessary
```

somewhere outside this function (better in (document).ready statement :))
Also to add: you have

```
 windowPos > lastWindowPos
```

on a refreshed page you will not enter in this scope 
Ask if you want further assistance

Comment: Thanks Dimitar... but the sidebar functionality is inside the scroll function in the twentyfifteen theme too but when you refresh the page, it remains in the last sidebar position and it will be visible too : https://twentyfifteendemo.wordpress.com/ (make your browser screen height smaller and refresh the page, you will see).
Maybe it uses something what i did not copie... ?